# Force write.csv to include decimal point for numeric data type

Tags: r, export-to-csv

Is there a way to include decimal even for integer like values on numeric data types while writing to csv?

```r
f <- tempfile("d", fileext = ".csv")
write.csv(data.frame(x = as.numeric(c(1,2,3.3,4))), f, row.names = FALSE)
readLines(f)
#> [1] "\"x\"" "1"     "2"     "3.3"   "4"
unlink(f)
```

The above output should have been as below:

```
#> [1] "\"x\"" "1.0"     "2.0"     "3.3"   "4.0"
```

Comment: have you considered using `sprintf` with conditional precision printing?

Comment: Thank you for sharing. I am unsure how to use `sprintf` *easily* to create a wrapper around `write.csv` as a generic function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write_csv2` from `readr` does what you expect. Keep in mind that it uses a decimal `,` instead of a `.` so read data with e.g. `read.csv2`.

```
library(readr)

write_csv2(data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3.3, 4)), file = "file")

readLines("file")
[1] "x"   "1,0" "2,0" "3,3" "4,0"

read.csv2("file")
    x
1 1.0
2 2.0
3 3.3
4 4.0
```

Comment: Thank you! That is an interesting observation and some kind of alternative; but not the perfect one though. Python's Pandas actually does it without this kind of workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer by [Andre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76177186/9689416), I figured that I can use below approach as a quick fix without creating anymore new function to do the same task as I originally wanted:

```r
library(readr)
f <- tempfile("d", fileext = ".csv")
write_delim(
    readr:::change_decimal_separator(
        data.frame(x = as.numeric(c(1,2,3.3,4))),
        "."
    ), f, delim = ","
)
readLines(f)
#> [1] "x"   "1.0" "2.0" "3.3" "4.0"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-05 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>